# Java (ME) library for fixed-length record files

Tags: java, database, data-structures, mobile

I am looking for a library that can run on Java ME (Foundation Profile 1.1, CDC) and allows me to basically do something along the lines of

```
FILE OF type;
```

in Pascal.

Background: I need to have a largish (approx. 100MB) set of around 500.000 records for lookups by a known index value quickly. Do I really have to write this myself? Databases like Derby are way too big and bring lots of features (stored procedures, anyone?) I do not need.

Ideally I would just like to define a class with a few fields based on primitive types and Strings as a value holder object and persist these in a file I could - should the need arise - manually recover. That's why I am not too much into serialization. From the past I have fought several occasions of corrupted binary data files which could not be recovered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around for quite some time, I have finally come to [xBaseJ](http://xbasej.sourceforge.net) from SourceForge. It relies on `java.nio`, which is normally not included in the JavaME CDC profile, but we had a contractor port the relevant parts to the mobile J9 VM. Armed with this, we are now building our application on top of DBase III compatible files. Apart from being pretty reasonably fast, even on the mobile platform, this gives us access to a plethora of tools that can handle this format, without having to teach non-tech folks about a JDBC based DB admin tool they do not feel comfortable with.

There has just been a recent release of a whole eBook, called "The Minimum You Need To Know About xBaseJ", which is available for free from the project's website, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem here is establishing a correspondence between field names and columns in the file, as you really shouldn't assume that the class layout matches the field ordering in the source file.

If the file were to contain a header row then it's a simple matter of using reflection/introspection and shouldn't take more than a day to implement yourself.

Alternatively, you'll have to use an annotation of some sort to specify, for each field, where it appears in the file.

Have you instead considered alternative text serialization methods, such as CSV, JSON or XML using XStream?  These avoid the risks of binary corruption and would get you up and running faster, but might also impose a higher memory footprint which could be an issue as you're targeting a mobile device.

Comment: As you say, JavaME devices (embedded devices) as well as the limited set of APIs for the mobile Java editions, place serious restrictions on both available memory, processing power and the libraries I can use. Unfortunately most XML (and other plain text formats) require processing that is way too slow - no chance of storing 500.000 records and searching quickly in them.

I am currently looking into libraries for DBF file access - however they often rely on java.nio which is not part of JavaME either... I feel like back in the stone age...

Comment: Take a serious look at JSON then, it tends to have the smallest libraries, it's designed for efficiency, and is simple enough that rolling your own serialiser/deserialiser won't be painful.  The usual speed/size tradeoff applies with JSON libraries.